# Trying to fix a Django error calling a Module that doesn't exist for an SQLite Database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, django-models

I'm designing a website using Django and SQLite, using Models to parse information between the database and the front-end. I'm encountering errors that are limiting my developmental process, as I'll explain below. For reference, here's the code that I'm using with my Models:

```
# Internal = 0, Derived = 1.

class Grade(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="null")
    # classPage = models.ManyToManyField(classPage, related_name="_set")
    amegrade = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="null")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="null")
    type = models.BooleanField(default=1)

class Student(models.Model):
    studentName = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="null")
    age = models.CharField(default="13", max_length=3)
    house = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="null")
    bday = models.CharField(default="null", max_length=50)

class classPage(models.Model):
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="null")
    # classStudents = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name="_set")

class timetableItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="null")
    timeStart = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="null")
    timeEnd = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="null")
    

class dailyTimetable(models.Model):
    timetableItems = models.ManyToManyField(to=timetableItem)

class weeklyTimetable(models.Model):
    monday = models.OneToOneField(to=dailyTimetable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class sideViewButton(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="null")
    directory = models.URLField(max_length=100, default="null")

class Notice(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="null")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=10000, default="null")
```

I'm using Models in my Database to store information. That works all well and dandy, but I'm trying to migrate new changes to the project using python3 manage.py migrate, and I'm getting thrown an error that "TypeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str". I use Google Bard to help diagnose the issues and the over 100 lines (thereabouts) of error messages, and it says that one of my models is using a DateTime system incorrectly. It says: "The error message is telling you that the fromisoformat() method expects a string as its argument, but you are passing it a datetime.date object." This confuses me because I've tried to solve the error by replacing the DateFields with CharFields, but my project is still saying that I'm trying to use a Model that doesn't exist. Hopefully that makes sense?

Many thanks.

Comment: It sounds like your db is out of sync somehow and migrations think it's in a different state than it actually is. If this is just a local project and you don't really care about the data I suggest just deleting your sqlite.db file and running migrations from scratch to get to the current state. If you still get an issue when doing that, then it's a coding issue.

Comment: Whenever python shows you an error, it also shows a traceback that allows you to locate where in your code the error occurred. You didn't include that in your question, which makes it impossible for people here to find out _why_ the TypeError occurs. You can [edit] your question to add it. You will receive the best and fastest answers if you include a [mre] together with the full error message you get.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**if you are using practice project then**

you should first try

> python manage.py migrate app_name zero

and delete the migration file

and then run makemigrations and migrate again it should work because i tried these model in my system and worked fine for me